# Possible to change a job's priority after creation in kue?

Tags: node.js, kue

The requirement is simple, after creating a job in kue with a given priority, is it possible to change its priority (like `renice` in POSIX) before it's scheduled to run?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need.

It seems that `job.priority(level).update(fn)` works. `Job#save(fn)` could also be used as it calls `Job#update(fn)` if the job has already been saved.